# setInfoWindowAdapter does not render marker info windows

Tags: java, android, google-maps

it's my first question, so sorry for bad formatting or anything like this.

I'm trying to add info windows to markers, which are clustered by ClusterManager from google utils, but my item does not get rendered by my custom InfoWindowAdapter and that's what i'm trying to do.

After onMapReady callback, i initialize cluster manager like this:

```
        mClusterManager = new ClusterManager<>(this, mMap);
        mClusterManager.setRenderer(new ClusterMarkerRenderer(this, mMap, mClusterManager));
        mClusterManager.setOnClusterClickListener(cluster -> {
            LatLngBounds.Builder builder = LatLngBounds.builder();
            for (CarMapItem item : cluster.getItems()) {
                builder.include(item.getPosition());
            }
            final LatLngBounds bounds = builder.build();
            mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(bounds, 100));
            return true;
        });

        mMap.setInfoWindowAdapter(new InfoWindowCarAdapter(this));
```

ClusterMarkerRenderer Class (only important parts):

```
public class ClusterMarkerRenderer extends DefaultClusterRenderer<CarMapItem> {
    public ClusterMarkerRenderer(Context context, GoogleMap map, ClusterManager<CarMapItem> clusterManager) {
        super(context, map, clusterManager);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onBeforeClusterItemRendered(CarMapItem item, @NotNull MarkerOptions markerOptions) {
        if (item.getIcon() != null) {
            markerOptions.icon(item.getIcon());
        }

        if (!item.hasCustomBitmap()) {
            markerOptions.rotation(item.getRotation());
        }

        markerOptions.title(item.getName());
        markerOptions.anchor(0.5f, 0.5f);
        markerOptions.flat(true);
        markerOptions.infoWindowAnchor(0.5f, 0.5f);
        markerOptions.snippet(item.getImei() + "#" + item.getPosition().latitude
                + "#" + item.getPosition().longitude + "#" + item.getRotation() + "#" + item.getIconName() + "#" + item.getName());

        super.onBeforeClusterItemRendered(item, markerOptions);
    }
     
    @Override
    protected void onClusterItemRendered(@NotNull CarMapItem item, @NotNull Marker marker) {
        super.onClusterItemRendered(item, marker);
        marker.setTag(item);
    }
}
```

This is where i set marker options, before cluster item gets rendered, my icon is set and everything is fine, but after rendering, i just set my item as tag to retrieve information for drawing and it won't render anything after this. And there is my last class, InfoWindowCarAdapter:

```
public class InfoWindowCarAdapter implements GoogleMap.InfoWindowAdapter {

    private View myContentsView;
    private Activity context;


    @SuppressLint("InflateParams")
    public InfoWindowCarAdapter(Activity context) {
        this.context = context;
        myContentsView = context.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.item_car_info, null);
    }

    @Override
    public View getInfoContents(Marker marker) {
        Log.e(TAG, "GET INFO CONTENTS FROM MARKER");
        CarMapItem object = (CarMapItem) marker.getTag();
        if (object != null) {
            TextView tvTitle = myContentsView.findViewById(R.id.txt_car_name);
            if (object.getItemType() == 1) {
                ((TextView) myContentsView.findViewById(R.id.txt_adit_info)).setText(String.format(Locale.getDefault(), "%s", Helper.getFormatedAlarmWithVars(context, object.getSpeed(),
                        object.getIconName(), object.getVar2())));
                (myContentsView.findViewById(R.id.txt_status)).setVisibility(View.GONE);
                (myContentsView.findViewById(R.id.ic_status_icon)).setVisibility(View.GONE);
            } else {
                TextView title = myContentsView.findViewById(R.id.txt_status);
                ImageView icon = myContentsView.findViewById(R.id.ic_status_icon);


                ((TextView) myContentsView.findViewById(R.id.txt_adit_info)).setText(String.format(Locale.getDefault(), "%s", "Click for more info"));

                if (object.getCarEngineStatus() == 1) {
                    title.setText(String.format(Locale.getDefault(), "%d KM/h", object.getSpeed()));
                } else {
                    title.setText(Helper.formatSecondPrecise(context, object.getLastActivityTime()));
                }

                icon.setImageResource(Helper.getIconResIdByCarStatus(object.getVehicleStatus()));

                (myContentsView.findViewById(R.id.txt_status)).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                (myContentsView.findViewById(R.id.ic_status_icon)).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }


            tvTitle.setText(object.getName());

            return myContentsView;
        }
        return myContentsView;
    }

    @Override
    public View getInfoWindow(Marker marker) {
        return null;
    }

}
```

When this class gets called, get info contents never does neither get info window, even tho i tried to log messages, still no output from this class, only from constructor.

Can u help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone needs, i fixed it myself, and here is the mistake: In my activity, where i set InfoWindowAdapter to google maps object, i had to set ClusterManager's MarkerManager to Google Maps object and then set my custom info window adapter to cluster manager's marker collection just like this:

```
mMap.setInfoWindowAdapter(mClusterManager.getMarkerManager());
mClusterManager.getMarkerCollection().setInfoWindowAdapter(new InfoWindowCarAdapter(this));
```

if anybody needs this, it's here :)

Comment: Same for setOnInfoWindowClickListener, u have to set it for ClusterManager's getMarkerCollection object.